# Why does the iterator of List in STL use the (*node).data instead of node->data?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I recently view the source code of SGI STL. I want to know whether I can use the "->" operator to replace the `(*node).data` to implement the `operator*()`, like this:

```
reference operator*() const {return (*node).data;}
```

replaced by:

```
reference operator*() const {return node->data;}
```

in addition:

node is a pointer which points to a struct object, like this:

```
template<class T>
struct __list_node {
    typedef void * void_pointer;
    void_pointer prev;
    void_pointer next;
    T data;
};
```

Comment: You can, but what's the point?

Comment: Probably, yes. What type is `node` and does it overload `operator->` or unary `operator*`?

Comment: node is a pointer which points to a struct __list_node {}

Comment: @herohuyongtao They usually should be, but nothing enforces that. Just like `++a` and `a++` could affect `a` in different ways – or just like `c << n` could have side-effects and mean something different from bit-wise shifting, to name the ever-popular early overload changing an operator meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most cases (for example, when `node` is a pointer), these will be equivalent. The `x->y` operator is defined as being equivalent to `(*(x)).y`. However, it's possible to overload `operator*` or `operator->`, in which case they may not behave as you would expect (but they *should*).

As you have said, in this case `node` is just a pointer, so they are equivalent.

Comment: *"in which case they may not behave as you would expect"* -- But if they don't, please stop using that library. The author is a bad person.